# angular clean project folder architecture

Tags: angular, architecture, frontend, clean-architecture

I am curious about the project folder architecture in angular.

What folder should the service that collects only API communication be located and how should the folder be named?
In the case of components shared in common, which folder should be placed and how should the folder name be configured?
What folders should be configured under the app and feature folders, and what components should be placed under them?

Please understand that my English is not good and my writing is not good.